# the acc of last trajectory point in FollowJointTrajectory is not zero

Tags: ros, moveit, acceleration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,
I'm using MoveIt to plan a trajectory to reach certain. The trajectory is sent via FollowJointTrajectory action. I intend to receive the goal in FollowJointTrajectory and interpolate between the traj points in follow_joint_trajectory/goal using  quintic spline, then send these points to motor.

But I found the acceleration of the last trajectory point is not zero, while the velocity is zero, the joint position is desired position. I don't know why the last acc is not zero. This would cause oscillation after this point.

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380919/the-acc-of-last-trajectory-point-in-followjointtrajectory-is-not-zero/) by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2021-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-23**:
I'd suggest to check whether MoveIt `master` version (or anything newer than Kinetic) has this problem.

**Comment by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on 2021-06-23**:
checked using the demo.launch in panda_moveit_config on ros noetic. The problem still exists.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-06-24**:
This depends on the retiming algorithm you use (IPTP, TOTG, TOPPRA...). Did you try different ones? IIRC the ones that are open-source aren't jerk-limited.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-24**:\

> TOPPRA

do we already have a MoveIt integration for that?

**Comment by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on 2021-06-24**:
I tried to use `AddIterativeSplineParameterization` instead of the default `AddTimeParameterization` just now. seems it works. the acc of last point is 0.

I don't have TOPPRA currently.

Thanks very much@gvdhoorn@fvd

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-06-24**:
There's no MoveIt integration for TOPPRA yet. I'll post an answer.

**Comment by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on 2021-06-26**:
BTW: Is there any retiming algorithm that can consider the max jerk?  The trajectory given by "AddIterativeSplineParameterization" has a large jerk.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-06-26**:
I don't know about open-source ones, but there are at least [some commercial options](https://picknik.ai/smoothing/jerk-free/trajectory/2020/05/12/solutions-for-trajectory-smoothing-tracksuite-and-reflexxes.html).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-26**:
[AIS-Bonn/TopiCo](https://github.com/AIS-Bonn/TopiCo) can do this. There isn't a ready-to-use MoveIt plugin for it though afaik.

`pantor/ruckig` is a jerk-limited, time-optimal implementation of a position/velocity controller. It does not do paths (yet), but it can be used on the execution side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This a function of the time parameterization algorithm that you use. [This tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/time_parameterization/time_parameterization_tutorial.html) describes how to apply different time parameterization methods to your plans manually. The default time parametrization is added by the `AddTimeParameterization` planning adapter (`add_time_parametrization.cpp`), which you can replace with the `AddTimeOptimalParameterization` or `AddIterativeSplineParameterization` in your moveit_config's launch files.

Pull requests to add new methods such as TOPPRA are very welcome. A recent discussion on Github is [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2110).

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0